Is 1080p 60Hz a minimum display mode required by a modern PC BIOS?
I've been happily using Dell 2007FP displays for ages. The highest display mode they support is 1600 x 1200 at 60Hz. This was always enough for BIOS setup screen, until now. I just booted an ASRock NUC-125H R2 motherboard and the BIOS screen is in 1080p 60Hz video mode, not supported by Dell 2007FP.
I'm surprised they use high resolution for a simple text based BIOS setup screen. Until now, I could set up the BIOS with a VGA display. Why would Asus make life difficult for users? I don't see a BIOS setting to change the video mode on startup. Is there a way to do it?
Has anyone seen other motherboards, which require 1080p 60Hz video mode just for BIOS setup screen?
Is 1080p 60Hz considered a hardware minimum requirement these days?
Are there motherboards requiring more than 1080p 60Hz just to show you a BIOS setup screen?

It seems that the problem is caused by video mode negotiation over HDMI bus on power up. I tried a different display, Lilliput FA1000, and it displays BIOS setup screen at 640 x 480, 63.4Hz mode. Dell 2007FP doesn't have HDMI port, so I'm using DVI to HDMI adapter, which didn't caused any issues with many PC models I used over the years. The question is why it is unable to negotiate a lower resolution with NUC-125H R2?

Here is more information about my Dell 2007FP display:
paul@cube:~$ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 7
No EDID on bus 8
No EDID on bus 9
No EDID on bus 10
No EDID on bus 11
1 potential busses found: 3
128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 3
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DELL 2007FP"
    ModelName "DELL 2007FP"
    VendorName "DEL"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 11 of 2009
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 410 310
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-83
    VertRefresh 56-76
    # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x1200, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
    Modeline    "Mode 0" +hsync +vsync 
EndSection


More detailed EDID from edid-decode:
  Established Timings I & II:
    IBM     :   720x400    70.081663 Hz   9:5     31.467 kHz     28.320000 MHz
    DMT 0x04:   640x480    59.940476 Hz   4:3     31.469 kHz     25.175000 MHz
    DMT 0x06:   640x480    75.000000 Hz   4:3     37.500 kHz     31.500000 MHz
    DMT 0x09:   800x600    60.316541 Hz   4:3     37.879 kHz     40.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x0b:   800x600    75.000000 Hz   4:3     46.875 kHz     49.500000 MHz
    DMT 0x10:  1024x768    60.003840 Hz   4:3     48.363 kHz     65.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x12:  1024x768    75.028582 Hz   4:3     60.023 kHz     78.750000 MHz
    DMT 0x24:  1280x1024   75.024675 Hz   5:4     79.976 kHz    135.000000 MHz
  Standard Timings:
    DMT 0x23:  1280x1024   60.019740 Hz   5:4     63.981 kHz    108.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x33:  1600x1200   60.000000 Hz   4:3     75.000 kHz    162.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x15:  1152x864    75.000000 Hz   4:3     67.500 kHz    108.000000 MHz
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 1:  1600x1200   60.000000 Hz   4:3     75.000 kHz    162.000000 MHz (367 mm x 275 mm)
                 Hfront   64 Hsync 192 Hback  304 Hpol P
                 Vfront    1 Vsync   3 Vback   46 Vpol P
    Display Product Serial Number: 'G324H93C27GL'
    Display Product Name: 'DELL 2007FP'
    Display Range Limits:
      Monitor ranges (GTF): 56-76 Hz V, 30-83 kHz H, max dotclock 170 MHz

For comparision, EDID from Lilliput FA1000 display, which succesfully negotiates 640x480 resolution for BIOS screen of NUC-125H R2:
  Established Timings I & II:
    IBM     :   720x400    70.081663 Hz   9:5     31.467 kHz     28.320000 MHz
    DMT 0x04:   640x480    59.940476 Hz   4:3     31.469 kHz     25.175000 MHz
    Apple   :   640x480    66.666667 Hz   4:3     35.000 kHz     30.240000 MHz
    DMT 0x05:   640x480    72.808802 Hz   4:3     37.861 kHz     31.500000 MHz
    DMT 0x06:   640x480    75.000000 Hz   4:3     37.500 kHz     31.500000 MHz
    DMT 0x08:   800x600    56.250000 Hz   4:3     35.156 kHz     36.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x09:   800x600    60.316541 Hz   4:3     37.879 kHz     40.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x0a:   800x600    72.187572 Hz   4:3     48.077 kHz     50.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x0b:   800x600    75.000000 Hz   4:3     46.875 kHz     49.500000 MHz
    Apple   :   832x624    74.551266 Hz   4:3     49.726 kHz     57.284000 MHz
    DMT 0x10:  1024x768    60.003840 Hz   4:3     48.363 kHz     65.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x11:  1024x768    70.069359 Hz   4:3     56.476 kHz     75.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x12:  1024x768    75.028582 Hz   4:3     60.023 kHz     78.750000 MHz
    DMT 0x24:  1280x1024   75.024675 Hz   5:4     79.976 kHz    135.000000 MHz
  Standard Timings:
    DMT 0x23:  1280x1024   60.019740 Hz   5:4     63.981 kHz    108.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x24:  1280x1024   75.024675 Hz   5:4     79.976 kHz    135.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x10:  1024x768    60.003840 Hz   4:3     48.363 kHz     65.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x13:  1024x768    84.996690 Hz   4:3     68.677 kHz     94.500000 MHz
    DMT 0x09:   800x600    60.316541 Hz   4:3     37.879 kHz     40.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x0c:   800x600    85.061274 Hz   4:3     53.674 kHz     56.250000 MHz
    DMT 0x04:   640x480    59.940476 Hz   4:3     31.469 kHz     25.175000 MHz
    DMT 0x07:   640x480    85.008312 Hz   4:3     43.269 kHz     36.000000 MHz
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 1:  1280x1024   75.024675 Hz   5:4     79.976 kHz    135.000000 MHz (360 mm x 290 mm)
                 Hfront   16 Hsync 144 Hback  248 Hpol P
                 Vfront    1 Vsync   3 Vback   38 Vpol P
    Display Product Serial Number: '0'
    Display Product Name: 'AS4637       '
    Display Range Limits:
      Monitor ranges (GTF): 56-85 Hz V, 24-80 kHz H, max dotclock 140 MHz

Both displays show 640x480 video modes, but only Lilliput can negotiate it successfully. Why is that?
